# A certain formal power series equals the zeta function of a curve

Tags: representation-theory, finite-fields, zeta-functions, formal-power-series

Be $X$ a projective, geometrically connected and smooth curve over the finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$. Then one can define the following series, i.e. the zeta function of the curve: $$Z(t) = \exp\left(\sum_{d} \frac{\left|X(\mathbb{F}_{q^d})\right|}{d}t^d\right)$$
I would like to show that the following series (where, hopefully, there are no previous mistakes in its computation) is equal to the zeta: $$\mathcal{E}(t) = 1 + \sum_{d>0} q^d t^d \sum_{\sum_i n_i \deg(x_i)=d} \prod (1-q^{-\deg(x_i)})$$
where the inner sum is taken over all possible combinations of distinct closed points $x_i$ and positive integers $n_i$ with the property that $\sum_i n_i \deg(x_i) = d$, and the product is then taken over all the $x_i$ appearing in the sum.

I tried rewriting the series as the product over all $k$-tuple of points $x_i$, $k$ varying, of the sums of terms $1-q^{-\deg(x_i)}$, the sum being taken over the $k$-tuples of positive integers $(n_1, \dots, n_k)$, but i could not find an easier expression. In particular, the presence of the powers of $q$ throws me off, it seems like they should cancel out but i am not convinced how this should happen.

The question arose in the study of Hall algebras of curves, so if you have any idea how to use Hall-theoretic methods to simplify the problem, feel free to share your thought. I have tried some other other approaches using formal properties of the Hall algebras, like the Green product, but to no avail, and i believe there should be an "elementary" way to show the equivalence.

Thanks in advance for any comment or answer.

Comment: It doesn't even give the correct $d=1$ term.  (You get $(q-1)\nu_1$ instead of $\nu_1$.)

Comment: To check the normalization (see the comment from user10354138) you should carry out the computation in the simplest possible case where $X$ is the projective line with $|X(\Bbb{F}_{q^n})|=1+q^n$. Remember (from calculus and/or complex analysis) that 
$$\log (1-t)=-\sum_d\frac{t^d}d,$$
implying $$Z(t)=\exp(-\log(1-t)-\log(1-qt))=\frac1{(1-t)(1-qt)}=1+(q+1)t+\cdots.$$ Does this match your $\mathcal{E}(t)$?